# Maximum value of the determinant formed from the matrix of 0 and n

Tags: algorithm, math, matrix

Given a number k , a number n
We have to form a K*K square matrix using just the numbers 0 and n
such that it has maximum possible determinant
We have to write a program that returns such determinant for given values of k and n

for example if k = 3 and n = 13

13 13 0

0 13 13

13 0 13

ie for k = 3 and any non negative value of n
required matrix is

n n 0

0 n n

n 0 n

Its not a programming assignment or homework I was doing [this](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-determinant-matrix-every-values-either-0-n/) question on geeksforgeeks and found this question as an extension and could not solve for a general case.

Comment: Forget the `n`. You can replace all `n`s with `1`s and calculate a determinant. Let's call it a 'basic determinant'. Then the determinant of your 0-and-n's matrix is just a base determinant times `n` rised to power `k`. So basically you need to maximze a determinant of a 0-and-1's matrix. However, for negative `n` and odd `k` the resulting determinant will be negative. In such case just swap any two columns or any two rows to get the determinant positive.

Comment: Ya you are correct ans would be same as    (ans for(k,n = n))                                    = ((ans for(k,n = 1))*(n^k)) but how to calculate for n= 1 and given k what  maximum value of determinant would be  supposing n and k are non negative for time being

Comment: @CiaPan can you please suggest method for n = 1 and and any specific k such thak K >= 1

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this page at Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HadamardsMaximumDeterminantProblem.html) 
and [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard's_maximal_determinant_problem).

If I understand correctly, the problem is unsolved! Perhaps you need to search for heuristic algorithms.